# Question about SetParent API, it doesn't work on Windows 11

Tags: processstartinfo, setparent, window-style, setwindowlong, movewindow

Good evening everyone
So sorry for my mediocre english

I have a question about the SetParent API. When I run the window on **Windows 10**, it works correctly and contains any program I want

But when the program is executed on **Windows 11**, it does nothing, and Notepad, for example, runs normally and belongs to the desktop, and not to the container in my window.

This is what I am currently using:

```
Public Class WindowsApiSetAnyWindowParent
    Public Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (
                                                       ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr,
                                                       ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr
                                                       ) As IntPtr
    Public Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowLongPtrA" (
                                                                                  ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                                                                                  ByVal nIndex As Integer,
                                                                                  ByVal dwNewLong As Long
                                                                                  ) As Long
    Public Declare Function MoveWindow Lib "user32.dll" (
                                                        ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                                                        ByVal x As Integer,
                                                        ByVal y As Integer,
                                                        ByVal cx As Integer,
                                                        ByVal cy As Integer,
                                                        ByVal repaint As Boolean
                                                        ) As Boolean
    Public Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "PostMessageA" (
                                                                              ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                                                                              ByVal Msg As UInteger,
                                                                              ByVal wParam As Long,
                                                                              ByVal lParam As Long
                                                                              ) As Boolean
    Public Const SWP_NOOWNERZORDER As Integer = &H200
    Public Const SWP_NOREDRAW As Integer = &H8
    Public Const SWP_NOZORDER As Integer = &H4
    Public Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW As Integer = &H40
    Public Const WS_EX_MDICHILD As Integer = &H40
    Public Const SWP_FRAMECHANGED As Integer = &H20
    Public Const SWP_NOACTIVATE As Integer = &H10
    Public Const SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS As Integer = &H4000
    Public Const SWP_NOMOVE As Integer = &H2
    Public Const SWP_NOSIZE As Integer = &H1
    Public Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = -16
    Public Const WS_VISIBLE As Integer = &H10000000
    Public Const WM_CLOSE As Integer = &H10
    Public Const WS_CHILD As Integer = &H40000000
End Class
```

So i called:

```
Dim TheNotePad As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")
                        TheNotePad.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
                        Dim TheProcess As Process = Process.Start(TheNotePad)
                        TheProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
                        WindowsApiSetAnyWindowParent.SetParent(TheProcess.MainWindowHandle, HostTabPanel.Handle)
                        WindowsApiSetAnyWindowParent.SetWindowLong(TheProcess.MainWindowHandle, WindowsApiSetAnyWindowParent.GWL_STYLE, WindowsApiSetAnyWindowParent.WS_VISIBLE)
                        WindowsApiSetAnyWindowParent.MoveWindow(TheProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, HostTabPanel.Width, HostTabPanel.Height, True)
                        TheNotePad.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
```

[image]

**Many thanks for any help**

Comment: When I watched the value of TheProcess.MainWindowHandle, I found that in Windows 11 it is always 0

It seems that the problem stems from here